# Multi-Table Selfjoins - is there a good way to do this?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, self-join

I was trying to extract some info from the database using this query,

```
SELECT dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.Customer_id
, dbo.tblCustomer.Company
, dbo.tblDevices.device_id
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID
, dbo.tblDriverType.DriverType
, dbo.tblGroups.GroupName
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.ReportBy
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.TripTimeFilter
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.chkWeekEndTravel
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekdayStart
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekDayEnd
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekEndFrom
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekEndTo
, dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.ReportType
FROM dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup
FULL JOIN dbo.tblCustomer
ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.Customer_id = dbo.tblCustomer.Customer_id
FULL JOIN dbo.tblDriverType
ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID = dbo.tblDriverType.DriverType_id
FULL JOIN dbo.tblGroups
ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID = dbo.tblGroups.Group_id
FULL JOIN dbo.tblDevices
ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID = dbo.tblDevices.device_id
ORDER BY dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.Customer_id ASC
```

Is there another way to structure this query so that I can eliminate the NULL values?  dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID links everything together, but that column uses values from three different tables, so where there is no matching value, it returns NULL for all of the other columns selected where no matching join value was present.

Comment: An example of both what you get with this query and what you would *like* to get instead might clarify your intention a bit better.

Comment: use INNER JOIN if you don't want NULL values for right table

Comment: Sorry I am noob.  I get the results I want in the query but there are rows with NULL entries for every column except the column itself (ie a row where only dbo.tblDevices.device_id has an entry).  I think this is because dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID cannot always map to the related table.  But if I don't use FULL the second and third joins can't be completed.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN if you want to get NULLs.  I've worked with SQL since 97 and I've never used FULL JOIN.   FULL JOIN is like the old ANSI style back when people used "FROM table1, table2, table3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want intersection of tables. If so user inner join.

```
SELECT dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.Customer_id
    , dbo.tblCustomer.Company
    , dbo.tblDevices.device_id
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID
    , dbo.tblDriverType.DriverType
    , dbo.tblGroups.GroupName
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.ReportBy
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.TripTimeFilter
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.chkWeekEndTravel
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekdayStart
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekDayEnd
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekEndFrom
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.WeekEndTo
    , dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.ReportType
FROM dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.Customer_id = dbo.tblCustomer.Customer_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblDriverType ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID = dbo.tblDriverType.DriverType_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblGroups ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID = dbo.tblGroups.Group_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblDevices ON dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.DeviceMasterID = dbo.tblDevices.device_id
ORDER BY dbo.AfterHoursParameterSetup.Customer_id ASC
```